# Flutter gif image glitch

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I do not know how to correctly explain, but I'll try. On my auth page, at the top of it, I have a GIF logo (without repeat). So auth page works like this:

1. logo animation running (for around 3 seconds)
2. after 3 seconds all other content appears (thanks to [delayed_display](https://pub.dev/packages/delayed_display))

And all works fine. But if I logged in to the app, and press log out, I'm redirected back to the same login page (as expected), but GIF not playing again, and simply freezing on the first frame. I can assume it's probably because my GIF set up to not repeat and it cached in flutter??? But if it's cached, why do I see it at the beginning of the animation, but not the final frame???

**Also not about how authentication works**. I'm using GetX for state management. So basically all is moving around `authUser` observable from `AuthenticationController`, and I have a `Wrapper` page which checks if `authUser` is not null to show `DashboardScreen`, otherwise `AuthScreen`.

Here is the `AuthScreen` with the gif image itself:

```dart
class AuthScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  AuthScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final AuthenticationController _authController =
      Get.find<AuthenticationController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.asset('assets/images/n2mu_animated_logo.gif'), <=== here is the GIF
          DelayedDisplay(
              delay: const Duration(seconds: 4),
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, right: 20, left: 20),
                child: Center(
                    child: Column(children: [
                  RichText(
                      text: const TextSpan(children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'Hey, let verify:',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),
                    ),
                  ])),
                  Obx(() => AnimatedSwitcher(
                        duration: const Duration(microseconds: 300),
                        child: (_authController.verificationCodeSent.value ==
                                false)
                            ? PhoneNumberWidget() <== widget to shop phone number input
                            : SmsVerificationWidget(), <== SMS verification widget
                      )),
                ])),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, you should use `evict()` method of the AssetImage widget. Here is more info https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51775#issuecomment-680997795